# Remove text from iOS navigation back bar button.

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I want to remove the text from the navigation bar left button but I've looked everywhere and can't find anything. I want the button to just display an image and it does that but with the text over laying it. How can I remove the text?

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage"];
CGRect frameimg = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
UIButton *yourButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frameimg];
[yourButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *button =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:yourButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=button;
```

Answer (score 0):

just set

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"";
```

in the previous viewcontroller

Comment: yea but this also removes the title